# Using SSIS data flow rows in external DLL

Tags: c#, ssis

In many of our SSIS data flows across packages we call into a service of some kind from a script transform. I would like to promote reuse by eliminating web service related code and object creation/conversion code from the script tasks, and put it into a small set of reusable libraries.

I would like to pass the row data to the common methods, without having 20, 30, 40 etc. method parameters, and would like to hear from the community how to effectively pass row(s) from SSIS to external libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you go to the tools choose toolbox items, you can add specific DLLs to the toolbox in BIDS. Then you can use them like any other task. All of your developers would have to have the components you want to use added to their BIDS. We have done this with several locally created components and a few we got from other sources. Not knowing exactly what things you want to add, I can't guarantee you can add them, but it's what I woudl try first.